# После добавления связей между таблицами, ошибка - undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

После добавления связей между таблицами, при загрузке главной страницы стала вылазить ошибка - undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass

Вот контроллер, который по умолчанию:

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.order(:title)
  end
end
```

вьюшка индекс

```
<% if notice %>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>
<h1>Your Pragmatic Catalog</h1>
<% @products.each do |product| %>
<div class="entry">
<%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
<h3><%= product.title %></h3>
<%= sanitize(product.description) %>
<div class="price_line">
<span class="price"><%= number_to_currency(product.price, :unit =>" &pound")   %></span>
<%=button_to 'Add to cart', line_items_path(product_id: product) %>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Модель

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :line_items
 before_destroy : ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item

  attr_accessible :title, :description, :image_url, :price

  validates :title, :description, :image_url, :price,  presence: true
  validates :price,  numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
  validates :title, uniqueness: true

  def ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item
     if line_items.empty?
      return true
     else
      errors.add(:base, " существуют товарные позиции")
       return false
     end

end
```

развернутый trace - http://pastebin.com/iz7TU4XW

Comment: Ответ не обещаю, но попробуйте добавить к своему вопросу ссылку на pastebin.com с развёрнутым stack trace

Comment: перезагрузил сервер, сейчас уже вылазит ошибка undefined method `each' for 0:Fixnum. Хочу добавить новый продукт, перехожу на .../products/new выдает ошибку undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass

Comment: help please!

Comment: @dborovsky, дайте пожалуйста код модели line_items

Answer (score 1):

уже разобрался, before_destroy : ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item
 - лишний пробел